# the function is convex on two different intervals, when the function is convex on the union the intervals

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, convex-analysis

If a real function is convex on the interval $I_1$ and $I_2$, respectively, does there a sufficient and necessary condition to determine when $f$ is convex on $I_1\cup I_2$?

Consider the function

$f(x) = \begin{cases} (x+1)^2 & \text{if $x \leq 0$} \\ (x-1)^2 & \text{if $x > 0$} \end{cases}.$
$f$ is convex on $(–\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$, but $f$ is not convex on $(–\infty, \infty)$.

Consider another function

$f(x)=x^3(1-x)$, $f$ is convex on $(–\infty,0]$ and $[\frac{1}{2},\infty)$, $f$ is also convex on  $(–\infty,0]\cup[\frac{1}{2},\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Convexity is only defined on convex domains. So your intervals would need to be adjacent and the rule would be the usual one.

Comment: But in many reference books, the convexity is defined on open intervals. Are there any reference books about the generalization as you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, open intervals, but I question whether they're often defined on unions of intervals. Perhaps you are asking if there is possible a convex function defined on the union of your intervals and everything in between? There are scores of books on convexity. Have you looked at the Wiki? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function